# How to compute the vector of the means in Gaussian process progression?

Tags: regression, gaussian-process

In the following, scalars are denoted with italic lowercases (e.g., $k,\, b_f$), vectors with bold lowercases (e.g., $\mathbf{s},\, \mathbf{x}_i$), and matrices with italic uppercases (e.g., $W_f$).

---

### Objective

A Gaussian process (GP) is defined as a collection of random variables, any finite number of which have a joint Gaussian distribution. A GP $f(\mathbf{x})$ is completely specified by its mean function $m(\mathbf{x})$
and covariance function $k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}'),$ also called *kernel*, defined as:
\begin{align*}
m(\mathbf{x}) &= \mathbb{E}[f(\mathbf{x})], \\
k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}') &= \mathbb{E}[(f(\mathbf{x})-m(\mathbf{x}))(f(\mathbf{x}')-m(\mathbf{x}'))].
\end{align*}

Let:

- ${X = (\mathbf{x}_1,\dotsc,\mathbf{x}_q)}$ be the training inputs
- $ {\mathbf{f} = (f(\mathbf{x}_1)\dotsc,f(\mathbf{x}_q))}$ be the training outputs
- $X^* = (\mathbf{x}_{q+1},\dotsc,\mathbf{x}_{s})$ be the test inputs
- $\mathbf{f}^* = (f(\mathbf{x}_{q+1})\dotsc,f(\mathbf{x}_{s}))$ be the test outputs.

Assume the training set isn't contaminated with samples from the test set, i.e.: $X \cup X^* = \mathcal{X},$ and $X \cap X^* = \emptyset$.

Note that $\mathbf{f}$ is known, and $\mathbf{f}^*$ is unknown. 
**The goal is to find the distribution of $\mathbf{f}^*$ given $X^*, X$ and $\mathbf{f}$.**

---

### Solution

The joint distribution of $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{f}^*$ according to the prior is

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{f} \\ \mathbf{f}^*
 \end{bmatrix}
 \sim 
 \mathcal{N} \left(  \begin{bmatrix} 
      \mathbf{m} \\ \mathbf{m}^*
      \end{bmatrix},
      ~
      \begin{bmatrix}
      K(X,X) & K(X,X^*) \\
      K(X^*,X) & K(X^*,X^*) \\
      \end{bmatrix}
    \right)
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{m}\,,\,\mathbf{m}^*$ is a vector of the means evaluated at all training and test points respectively, and $K(X,X^*)$ denotes the $q \times q^*$ matrix of the covariances evaluated at all pairs of training and test points, and similarly for $K(X,X),\, K(X^*,X)$ and $K(X^*,X^*)$.

Each element of the matrix $K(X,X^*)$ are denoted by $k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}')$. Ideally one should have $k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}') = \mathbb{E}[(f(\mathbf{x})-m(\mathbf{x}))(f(\mathbf{x}^*)-m(\mathbf{x}^*))]$ but this isn't feasible since one does not have access to $f(\mathbf{x}^*)$ and $m(\mathbf{x}^*)$. As a result, one resorts to some approximation of $k$  with some kernels taking only $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}^*$ as input e.g.:

- Linear: $k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}') = \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x}'$
- Cubic: $k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}') = 3  \left (\left (\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x}'  \right )^2 + 2\left ( \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x}' \right )^3  \right )$
- Absolute exponential: $k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}') = e^{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|} $
- Squared exponential: $k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}') = e^{-0.5|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|^2} $
- [etc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/129610/12359)

Conditioning the joint Gaussian prior on the observations yields $\mathbf{f}^* | X^*, X, \mathbf{f} \, \sim \, \mathcal{N} (\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ where

\begin{align}
 \mathbf{\mu} &= \mathbf{m}^* - K(X^*,X) K(X,X)^{-1}(\mathbf{f} - \mathbf{m}), \\
 \mathbf{\Sigma} &=  K(X^*,X^*) - K(X^*,X) K(X,X)^{-1} K(X,X^*). \notag 
\end{align}

---

### Question

How am I supposed to compute the vector of the means $\mathbf{m}^*$?

Comment: blah $x$ and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221704/results-of-softmax-regression-on-mnist-dataset)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at pages 16-17 of the Rasmussen and Williams GPML book: 
http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf

We can assume without loss of generality that the mean functions $\mathbf{m}$ and $\mathbf{m^*}$ are 0. I also think that you have an extra negative sign in your posterior, so then the joint distribution is:

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{f} \\ \mathbf{f}^*
 \end{bmatrix}
 \sim 
 \mathcal{N} \left(  \begin{bmatrix} 
      \mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{0}
      \end{bmatrix},
      ~
      \begin{bmatrix}
      K(X,X) & K(X,X^*) \\
      K(X^*,X) & K(X^*,X^*) \\
      \end{bmatrix}
    \right)
\end{equation*}

and the posterior is

\begin{equation*}\mathbf{\mu} = K(X^*,X) K(X,X)^{-1}\mathbf{f}\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\mathbf{\Sigma} =  K(X^*,X^*) - K(X^*,X) K(X,X)^{-1} K(X,X^*)\end{equation*}

Comment: (the latex equation issue was [Some Latex math equations not rendering immediately after edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288827/178179))

Comment: Thanks. I was really confused because I didn't see anything wrong with my latex.